# Implement Between and other functions as Expressions for LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have something like this:

```
public class HomeWork
{
    public DateTime Starts {get;set;}
    public DateTime Ends {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to make a LINQ query like this:

```
var xxx = from hwrk in HomeWorks
    where hwrk.Starts.Between(date1, date2) || hwrk.Ends.Between(date1, date2) || 
        date1.Beetween(hwrk.Starts, hwrk.Ends) || date2.Between(hwrk.Starts, hwrk.Ends)
    select hwrk;
```

I can make an extension that works with DateTime but I need that the extension works with LINQ to SQL too.

I found some examples that uses the Where method internally, but that works on IQueryable interface. But I need that it works with individual Properties. On some examples they uses Expressions, but I cant find an example that do something like that.

Can you give an example of an extension that works on Properties and regular variables and also works with LINQ to SQL? or simply this is something that I cannot do?

Comment: Why extension does not work with Linq to SQL?

Comment: is the `HomeWorks` collection some kind of DB-context (from Linq2Sql or EF)? If not then I don't see where you even use Linq2Sql. If so this should work as is (ok - not sure if Between gets translated into SQL but you can just expand it into your usual < .. > thing - just give it a try)

Comment: Sorry for that, yes, is a collection from a DB context.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a function that returns you a "between" expression and then make use of [LinqKit's AsExpandable](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) which allows you to plug reusable expressions into your lambdas.

It'd be pretty complicated though and I wouldn't recommend doing it in this particular situation.  I think it'd be simpler to just do it manually, it would be repetitive, but it'd be simpler and easier to maintain.

That being said, I've implemented it below using expressions so you can see the approach.

The first step is to create a method which returns your "between" expression.  I've implemented this using the `IComparable` interface so you can use this for any comparable type.

```
public static Expression<Func<TComparable, TComparable, TComparable, bool>> Between<TComparable>(this TComparable thisComparable) where TComparable : IComparable
{
    return (value, lower, upper) => lower.CompareTo(value) <= 0 && value.CompareTo(upper) <= 0;
}
```

You can then consume it like so:

```
var between = Extensions.Between<DateTime>();
```

The expression can be plugged into your query using LinqKit's `AsExpandable` and `Invoke` methods:

```
var query = from m in context.Members.AsExpandable()
            where between.Invoke(m.CreatedDate, startDate, endDate)
            select m;
```

This results in the following SQL when using Linq to SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2012-09-13 11:01:10.103'
DECLARE @p1 DateTime = '2012-09-20 11:01:10.103'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[MemberID], [t0].[Firstname], [t0].[Surname], [t0].[Email], [t0].[CreatedDate]
FROM [Member] AS [t0]
WHERE (@p0 <= [t0].[CreatedDate]) AND ([t0].[CreatedDate] <= @p1)
```

Comment: This is the closes solution to my problem, I will check LinqKit's library to see if that fill my requirements, but that seems to be the answer to my questions, hehehehe :), thank you DoctaJonez.

Answer (score 0):

I may not answer directly your generic question about extending the Linq2SQL, but from your example, you are looking for homework which starts or ends within a time slot. In terms of logic, given that `start < end`, you can simplify do this:

```
where hwrk.Starts <= date2 && hwrk.Ends >= date1
```

Comment: Yes Jon48, I can enter the lambda expression like you say, but I dont want to type the same expression everytime and I have other expression different from that that I use a lot. Thats the reason that I want to know how to implemente "extenssions" like this one, by the way, the code that I posted is a little example of what I whant to do, not only compare that if a time slot containst a spefic datetime.

Comment: I have severall "extensions" that may receive more that two extra parameters that I need to translate to SQL, that one was only an example. Also, there will be other developers that must use my extenssions on IQueryable objects. Thats the main reazon that I need to do that, and be able to modify the internal workings if need it to and dont change several code files looking for lambda expressions  that may be diferent fro file to file. I hope that you understand my point. thanks.

Comment: No worries. This is why I precised that this was not answering your question about extentions, but I was just making sure that if this was your only requirement, you were not overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

What you found about using the `IQueryable` interface is the way to go, you cannot do what you want in that way, you have to take your expression and treat it so that the Linq to SQL provider can understand it, and the only way I know is:

- writing 'dummy' implementations of your `Between` method as extension method of `DateTime`
- write an `IQueryable<T>` extension method (for example `Expand`) that you will call instead of `Where`, passing it the same predicate
- inside `Expand` you will have to analyze the expression tree you receive and generate a new one where your `Between` calls are translated in `and` expressions of `<=` and `=>` checks, which Linq to SQL will understand

If your problem is just with this specific case, I'd do what Jon48 said :)

Comment: do you have an example to do that? I'm new to expressions trees and the like.

Comment: Honestly, what you want to do is quite difficult without using some framework around. What DoctaJonez suggested is quite interesting, you should follow an approach like that one. You can read [this series of posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx) to have a bigger idea about what's involved in this problem. The you could also have a look at a framework like [Relinq](http://relinq.codeplex.com/). But it's quite though.